# 500 Internal Server error while trying to upload a file in form

Tags: php, file-upload

i am making a small application in php.everything works fine in wamp but when i am trying to upload a single fie. it shows me error like this.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete   your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

other forms without img works fine. i have cheked post_max_size in php.ini & upgrade it to 20M , but still problem exits.

For testing i have simple used..

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

    </form>
```

Comment: https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1903/Why+am+I+getting+a+500+Internal+Server+Error+message%3F

Comment: More information about this error may be available in the server error log. <-- Try this

Comment: can you show the php code please?

Comment: @Letmesee see, have posted my test code

Comment: @mic4ael can u please help me with this. i m facing this type of problem first time.

Comment: Everyone would help you, if we had more info.

Comment: @mic4ael what info u want? i have just installed wamp & making small app. all forms working fine in php & html , but when i need to upload single image, it shows me error , so that i have created test file to check image pro. & i have posted my testing code, it also shows error...

Comment: Can you post the server error log?

Comment: @mic4ael i am using wamp, where can i find server error log?

Comment: may be  .htacess  causing probs ? like some redirect rules .... etc?

Comment: @7-isnotbad i also thought like that,so i removed .htaccess file from directory

Comment: Try <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ....